# How can achieve Dynamic Forwarding(SOCK) in iOS? - libssh2 not supported what I use as alternative?

Tags: ios, proxy, ssh-tunnel, libssh2

I want to accept SOCKS5 clients like "ssh -D" does. Same like in Termius app(https://apps.apple.com/in/app/termius-ssh-sftp-client/id1176074088?mt=12) there is option to add Proxy Details(host, username & Pass). Then it will establish connection to the client through Proxy.

[image]

Let me know if any more details required.

Answer (score 0):

The Termius app does appear to leverage a bunch of Open Source Libraries:

- https://www.libssh2.org
- https://github.com/NMSSH/NMSSH

These provide an OpenSSH library and a Objective-C wrapper respectively.

The -D option you are interested in I believe is known as port forwarding.  There is a document to help at a code level with this

- https://github.com/open-quantum-safe/libssh/blob/OQS-master/doc/forwarding.dox

If you combine the above into your own app I think you should be able to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: I checked **forwarding.dox** but I couldn't found where do I put proxy credentials(host, username, pass and port). Please guide me if anything I missed out.

Comment: A mistake on my part, actually the SOCKS support is in the command line tool side of the tech stack, not in the libssh2 layer of the stack.  I see an implementation in channels.c of the command line tool; e.g. https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/e0f91aa9c2fbfc951e9ced7e1305455fc614d3f2/channels.c#L1509. So a solution would involve pulling this code in as well.  I get the feeling however you're looking for something out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thank You!, I checked https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/e0f91aa9c2fbfc951e9ced7e1305455fc614d3f2/channels.c#L1509 I'm able to add Proxy host and port but not username and without username I can't authenticate with proxy server.

is there any way I can create proxy tcp SOCK5 tunnel and then I will connect to actual server using libssh2?